How to get message of command used | discord.py
I need to create a button that will create a link to the discord message.
This is implemented in my code like this:
 transcript = await chat_exporter.export(tchannel)
        transcript_file = discord.File(io.BytesIO(transcript.encode()),
                                       filename=f"transcript-{tchannel.name}_{tchannel.id}.html") 
        transcript_message = await lchannel.send(file=transcript_file)
        tauthor = await bot.fetch_user(int(ticketInfo[1]))

....
transcript_url = ("https://mahto.id/chat-exporter?url="+ transcript_message.attachments[0].url)

But since discord has limited the duration of links, I need to create dynamic links. To do this, I need to add a button after clicking on which a link to view the saved ticket will be generated
Now I have such a code, but it doesn't work. Please help me find the errors
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        transcript_message = ctx.transcript_message
        transcript_url = ("http://v927477t.beget.tech/chat-exporter/?url="+ transcript_message.attachments[0].url)
        view=MyView()
        view.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="URL Button",style=discord.ButtonStyle.link,url=transcript_url))

I tried to run my code, but it doesn't work
I tried to create a button, but it doesn't work

First of all I don't know why you need a chat exporter when you need to link messages in discord, discord already has one built in but if you need it and will be using it you should specify which one are you using and why you need it.
Second of all if you weren't able to create a button in the first place you should first do that and research that.
So answering

I need to create a button that will create a link to the discord message.

class ViewWithButton(discord.ui.View):
    #Using @ decorator makes it easier for us to create a button
    #It automatically links to the function underneath so we don't need to use labels.
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click To Get Link",
                       style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def GiveLink(self,interaction,button):
        link = "Link of the discord message."
        message_content = "Link to the message: " + link
        await interaction.response.send_message(message_content,ephemeral=True,suppress_embeds=True)
        #Enabling ephemeral makes it only visible to who interacted with the message
        #Suppressing embeds to not turn link into an automatic embed

So this should be under your "ticket" opening function:
linkview = ViewWithButton(timeout=None) #Never timout
await ctx.send(view=linkview)


can we make another link button appear under this message?

Yes you can have 2 buttons for different links. Adding another @discord.ui.botton() will add another button and just the same way it will automatically link to the function below.
